# AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'insert_row'

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api

I have been following Tim's tutorial about Google Sheets API (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E)
and when I got to the `sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 9)` line it showed me an error,
all the other things are working just fine.
Important to say that Tim didn't have the same problem.

code :

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("Raz.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("RandomRaz").sheet1


row = sheet.row_values(3)
col = sheet.col_values(2)
cell = sheet.cell(1,2).value
insertRow = ["Test#123", "Url!"]
sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 9)
pprint(len(col))
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/#######/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/x.py", line 19, in <module>
    sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 9)
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'insert_row'
```

Comment: What version of gspread are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by writing `sheet.append_row(insertUrl)`, the problem being its add a new row at the end, you cant insert it. for me this is all I needed but people who will stack in the same problem and sheet.append_row() won't do the trick I don't know what to say to you